# python socket Function returning dictionary

Tags: python

```
import socket
def get_protnumber(prefix):
    return dict( (getattr(socket, a), a)

for a in dir(socket)
    if a.startswith(prefix))
        proto_fam = get_protnumber('AF_')
        types = get_protnumber('SOCK_')
        protocols = get_protnumber('IPPROTO_')


for res in socket.getaddrinfo('www.thapar.edu', 'http'):
    family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr = res


print 'Family        :', proto_fam[family]
print 'Type          :', types[socktype]
print 'Protocol      :', protocols[proto]
print 'Canonical name:', canonname
print 'Socket address:', sockaddr
```

Hello,
Can i replace this function with some other to get the same output?
I don't understand the following code:

```
return dict( (getattr(socket, a), a)
    for a in dir(socket)
      if a.startswith(prefix))
```

I mean what is happening here. Which part of the code is going to execute first.And how the values will be returned to dictionary?
if i do this:

```
def get_protnumber('AF_')[2]
```

it gives me AF_INET.Is 2 is assigned to INET by default or what?
What is getattr doing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict( (getattr(socket, a), a) for a in dir(socket) if a.startswith(prefix))
```

This is called a "comprehension." Admittedly I'm not sure what you'd call this exactly. A dict comprehension? An iteration? Who knows. Anyway, what you see happening here is a bunch of different things.

`getattr(socket, a)` is the first one. `socket` is an object with attributes that can be accessed like `socket.attribute_name` or with `getattr` which takes a string as the second argument and returns the value of the first parameter's attribute with that name(if it exists).

So `getattr(socket, a)` gets the attribute from `socket` with the name `a`. `a` is just a string from a list that is returned by the `dir` function, which returns a list of attributes of the object that is passed to it. The object can be a class, class instance, or a module.

So if we had:

```
class Socket:
  prop1 = 'a'
  prop2 = 'b'
```

and we did `dir(Socket)` we would get `['prop1', 'prop2']`.

So now we have a dict that is going to have the socket's attribute(this can be a method or a variable) for the key and the name as the value.

The last part is just checking if the attribute's name starts with the prefix provided.

```
>>> "Joe".startswith("J")
True
```

As to what happens first, it first gets the name of all attributes of the `socket` module and if it starts with the prefix given, then it gets added to the list of tuples(`(getattr(socket, a), a) for a in ...`) and then cast to a dict at the end.

Comment: that was better.I want to ask if getattr gets the attribute from the module.when i try key = socket.a it gives an attribute error why

Comment: `a` is a variable and `socket` doesn't have an `a` attribute. `getattr` is accessing it by it's name. So in our example `a` will be equal to `AF_somestuffhere` and we'll call the function like `getattr(socket, 'AF_somestuffhere')` which will return the attribute as if we had said `key = socket.AF_somestuffhere`

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict( (getattr(socket, a), a) for a in dir(socket) if a.startswith(prefix))
```

**is equal to**:

```
def _get_protnumber(prefix):                                                        
    prots = {}                                                                      
    attrs = dir(socket)                                                             
    for a in attrs:                                                                 
        if a.startswith(prefix):                                                    
            key = getattr(socket, a)                                                
            prots[key] = a                                                          
    return prots
```

Comment: It makes a pretty dictionary comprehension too: `{p: getattr(socket, p) for p in dir(socket) if p.startswith(prefix)}`

Comment: yes. But actually it should be: ```{ getattr(socket, p): p  for p in dir(socket) if p.startswith(prefix)}```

Comment: Ah, yes, got the key/value swapped.

Comment: that was better.I want to ask if getattr gets the attribute from the module.when i try **key = socket.a** it gives an attribute error why?

Comment: @Taimoor ```socket.a``` equal to ```getattr(socket, "a")```, socket doesn't have a attribute "a".

Comment: Thanks your function really helped